# Ubuntu: secure a folder & contents ?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, root

Assuming that the **root** user is pretty much off limits, how would one go about securing a folder & its contents so that viewing & using it or anything in it is denied?

e.g.

```
ls
```

would not show the folder if you were not root already &

```
cd secret_folder
```

is denied.

I'm trying to construct an environment that will let users (not root) do `apt-get`, etc. but make this folder & root operations off limits.

Any Knowledge on the subject fellas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, neither solution is completely correct. But... for future reference where is what works & why:

```
sudo visudo

# ... then put this at the end of the file
username ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get
```

*my experience was if you do this with the other combos of (ALL), other files seem to be locked*

---

**Secret Folder**

```
su
mkdir .some_other_folder
cd .some_other_folder
mkdir secret_folder
cd ../
chmod -R 700 .some_other_folder
chown -R root:root .some_other_folder
```

Final result :

> .some_other_folder/secret_folder

this works because `ls` will not even show `.some_other_folder`, but even if they do use something like `ls -las` , `cd .some_other_folder` is denied.

Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sudo to let users use apt-get, but if the folder is owned by root and set to 700, and the users are not in the wheel group, they should not be able to access it in any way.

visudo you can explicit grant the command

/usr/bin/apt-get

to the user(s) or group(s)

```
userA ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/apt-get
```

or

```
%groupA ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/apt-get
```

then, this is all you need:

```
chmod 700 secret_folder; chown root:root secret_foler
```

Comment: Wow, quick response & absolutely what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can stop access to a folder by clearing execute permission, but this won't hide it. To hide it you would need to enclose in another inaccessible folder, called something innocuous like `/.system`.

Logged in as **root** do the following:-

```
mkdir /.system
mkdir /.system/SecretFolder
chmod 700 /.system
```

If you make sure `apt-get` is owned by **root** and do:-

```
chmod a+s `which apt-get`
```

This gives users root access while running `apt-get` without needing to give them access to `sudo`.

Comment: If you give everyone root access while running apt-get, what stops them from apt-get 'ing a program that changes permissions on that folder... ?

Comment: Any such program would work only if it broke the security system, and I would not expect `apt-get` to have such a program available, and I am not sure it's even possible without cracking the root password.

Comment: This solution will give `E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.` though ... not sure why.

Comment: Sorry about that. I checked that set user ID works with an editor, and I could edit files in root directories, and perform commands requiring root privileges. I could run `sh` and get root privileges, but running `bash` got me original owner privileges. I can only surmise that `apt-get` calls bash scripts to do some of its work.